# How can I remove an annoying 'snap' noise each time I loop a wav file?

Tags: python, audio, wav

I'm trying to create a simple controllable and non-blocking looping wavplayer. The following class created using simpleaudio works, however, there is a brief pause and noticeable popping/snapping noise between each loop of the audio. I'm honestly not sure what's causing it and I'm not sure how I could fix it either than using a different audio module entirely. Any suggestions?

```
import simpleaudio as sa
from threading import Thread

class WavPlayer(Thread):
    def __init__(self,filepath,loop=False):

        self.loop = loop
        self.wav_obj = sa.WaveObject.from_wave_file(filepath)
        self.play_obj = None

        Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        self.play_obj = self.wav_obj.play() #initialize play buffer and play once

        while self.loop is True:
            if not self.play_obj.is_playing():
                print("played again")
                self.play_obj = self.wav_obj.play()

    def terminate(self):
        print("music terminated")
        self.play_obj.stop()
        self.loop = False
        self.join()

main_loop = WavPlayer("main_loop.wav",True)
menu_loop = WavPlayer("menu.wav",True)

main_loop.start()
z = input("Enter to end theme looping")
main_loop.loop = False

z = input("Enter to terminate music")
main_loop.terminate()

print("playing next song")
menu_loop.start()

cont = ''
while cont != 'n':
    cont = input("continue testing non-blocking? enter n to stop: ")

menu_loop.terminate()
```

[Filedropper link to menu_loop wav file](http://www.filedropper.com/menu_33)

[Filedropper link to main_loop wav file](http://www.filedropper.com/mainloop)

Comment: I don't have any "snaps" on my files. Could you share your WAV files?

Comment: @Alderven I added a file dropper link for both Wav files. It's weird because it plays smoothly in audacity, but when I loop it with my computer's regular audio player or the python code, it isn't.

Comment: I don't have any "snaps" with your WAV files either. Try to update python / libs.

Comment: Are you sure you don't really have an audio engineering question rather than a programming question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encounterded the same problem while programming a tuner that generates an infinitely long note from a limited number of samples (I used `pyaudio`, and a tuning note is a very simple sound, which makes the pops very obvious, but the remedy much easier).

If you loop a wave object like:

```
   **                    **
       *              *      *
         *          *          *
           *      *              *
              **                    **
```

... you'll hear a pop because of the large difference between the last and the first samples. Dropping a few samples until the last and the first sample match will eliminate the pops  (`simpleaudio` allows you to read the samples into `numpy` arrays which you then can truncate (slightly) until the first and last samples match).

Cutting at zero crossings is a special case of this, see [this discussion](https://www.reddit.com/r/Logic_Studio/comments/6git1b/how_to_get_rid_of_the_pop_sound_when_looping_an/). Of course, some sound libraries may already truncate your samples at zero crossings.

Before you take the trouble to extend your program to convert your samples to `numpy` arrays and truncating them, you first could try using a sound editor like Audacity and do it by hand, and then listen to the result.